# My class extends from 4 different interfaces. How to register and resolve using Structuremap IoC container

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I have 2 class say

```
public class Master : IService
public class Settings : ISettings
```

In constructor of Settings class I am calling,

```
var cache = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IService>();
```

I am registering in one StructureMap registry class constructor

```
For<IService>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<Master>();
For<ISettings>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<GetDefaultInstance()>();
```

Getting an exception

StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IService' in a static method where I am trying to resolve which concrete class to use in GetDefaultInstance()

```
public static ISettings GetDefaultInstance()
    {
        // overide default cacheprovider from config settings
        var configService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IService>();
        var appSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingKey.CacheProvider];
        var cacheProviderSetting = appSetting != null
                                       ?//Resolve My concrete class based on setting
                                       : configService.RetrieveDefaultCacheProvider();

        return CreateCacheProvider(cacheProviderSetting);
    }
```

Comment: Gut feeling is that a class called `Master`, that is implementing four interfaces has smashed through the separation of concerns principle and is well on its way to god-object status. So your route to solving this is not to fix the IoC issue, but to fix your class. Of course, I now look forward to you telling me each interface has one property and the class is 50 lines long ;)

Comment: Let me update my question, with a simpler example

Comment: Check that you configuring container before you create Settings class. Try to set breakpoints to `var cache = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IService>();` and to `For<IService>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<Master>();` and check what called first.

Comment: For<IService>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<Master>(); breakpoint hits and then cache = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IService>();